# Roslyn / IPropertySymbol / arrary return type

Tags: roslyn

I'm trying to return all the properties of a class, and the return type of each property using Roslyn (not reflection..)

I've gotten close, but then I hit a property that returns an array of strings (or perhaps an enumeration?) I'm fighting with how to find out the type within the array/collection...

public class msgClass  // part of a larger class, and referenced as Roslyn Document
string[] Lines {get; set;} //property in larger class of properties
...

```
var DocumentsInProject = await roslynUtilities.GetMembers<BasePropertyDeclarationSyntax>(msgClass);

foreach (var itemClassProperty in DocumentsInProject)
{
    var itemDeclaredSymbol = semanticModelOfDoc
        .GetDeclaredSymbol(itemClassProperty) as IPropertySymbol;
    if (itemDeclaredSymbol == null)
        throw new Exception($"property: {itemClassProperty}");

    var name = itemDeclaredSymbol.Name;
    //what does it return?
    string returnType = string.Empty;

    if (itemDeclaredSymbol.Type.IsReferenceType)
    {
        var typeofKind = itemDeclaredSymbol.Type.TypeKind;
        var typeincollection = itemDeclaredSymbol.Type.BaseType;
        var containingType = itemDeclaredSymbol.Type.ContainingType.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        returnType = itemDeclaredSymbol.Type.Name;
    }
}
```

If it isn't obvious  this is isn't production code - I'm hacking as I'm new to Roslyn, and I'm working on building a Visual Studio add-in that is reviewing classes in a project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need to convert property type symbol to `INamedTypeSymbol` or to `IArrayTypeSymbol`. You can check that the type is generic [un]bound type by `INamedTypeSymbol` and try to figure out the generic type parameters. It will allow to you receive collection's element type if type not just generic type, but collection. Casting to `IArrayTypeSymbol` will allow to you get array's element type. So your code should look like this:

```
...
if (itemDeclaredSymbol.Type is INamedTypeSymbol namedType && namedType.IsGenericType)
{
    // use namedType.TypeArguments if type is bound generic or namedType.TypeParameters if isn't
}
else if (itemDeclaredSymbol.Type is IArrayTypeSymbol arrayType)
{
    // use arrayType.ElementType as you want
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks! - this casting to ge the properties is tough to discover ... in terms of an array symbol - how do i tell the difference between string and string[], or Ienumerable<T>

Comment: @codeputer, 1) string and IEnumerable\`1 is `INamedTypeSymbol` when sting[] is `IArrayTypeSymbol` 2) IEnumerable\`1 is generic type when string isn't 3) You can check `ITypeSymbol.SpecialType` for comparison string, string[] and IEnumerable\`1 4) You can get type name from `ITypeSymbol` and compare them